# Web Services Deep XML Error

Tags: web-services, jpa, jaxb

The error occurs when I try to get a list from two tables 
i.e University and Usermaster, where Usermaster is the parent Table.

I am trying to get data from both tables based on University .

University Entity

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author 3gth
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "university")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "University.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM University u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "University.findByUniversityUname", query = "SELECT u FROM University u WHERE u.universityUname = :universityUname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "University.findByUniversityRegNo", query = "SELECT u FROM University u WHERE u.universityRegNo = :universityRegNo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "University.findByUniversityWebsite", query = "SELECT u FROM University u WHERE u.universityWebsite = :universityWebsite")})
public class University implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "universityUname")
    private String universityUname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "universityRegNo")
    private String universityRegNo;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "universityWebsite")
    private String universityWebsite;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
    @Column(name = "universityDesc")
    private String universityDesc;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "universityUname")
    private List<College> collegeList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "universityUname")
    private List<Student> studentList;
    @JoinColumn(name = "universityUname", referencedColumnName = "username", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Usermaster usermaster;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "universityUname")
    private List<Faculty> facultyList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "universityUname")
    private List<Course> courseList;

    public University() {
    }

    public University(String universityUname) {
        this.universityUname = universityUname;
    }

    public University(String universityUname, String universityRegNo, String universityWebsite, String universityDesc) {
        this.universityUname = universityUname;
        this.universityRegNo = universityRegNo;
        this.universityWebsite = universityWebsite;
        this.universityDesc = universityDesc;
    }

    public String getUniversityUname() {
        return universityUname;
    }

    public void setUniversityUname(String universityUname) {
        this.universityUname = universityUname;
    }

    public String getUniversityRegNo() {
        return universityRegNo;
    }

    public void setUniversityRegNo(String universityRegNo) {
        this.universityRegNo = universityRegNo;
    }

    public String getUniversityWebsite() {
        return universityWebsite;
    }

    public void setUniversityWebsite(String universityWebsite) {
        this.universityWebsite = universityWebsite;
    }

    public String getUniversityDesc() {
        return universityDesc;
    }

    public void setUniversityDesc(String universityDesc) {
        this.universityDesc = universityDesc;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<College> getCollegeList() {
        return collegeList;
    }

    public void setCollegeList(List<College> collegeList) {
        this.collegeList = collegeList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Student> getStudentList() {
        return studentList;
    }

    public void setStudentList(List<Student> studentList) {
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }

    public Usermaster getUsermaster() {
        return usermaster;
    }

    public void setUsermaster(Usermaster usermaster) {
        this.usermaster = usermaster;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Faculty> getFacultyList() {
        return facultyList;
    }

    public void setFacultyList(List<Faculty> facultyList) {
        this.facultyList = facultyList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Course> getCourseList() {
        return courseList;
    }

    public void setCourseList(List<Course> courseList) {
        this.courseList = courseList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (universityUname != null ? universityUname.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof University)) {
            return false;
        }
        University other = (University) object;
        if ((this.universityUname == null && other.universityUname != null) || (this.universityUname != null && !this.universityUname.equals(other.universityUname))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.University[ universityUname=" + universityUname + " ]";
    }

}
```

Usermaster Entity

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author 3gth
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "usermaster")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Usermaster.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Usermaster u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Usermaster.findByUsername", query = "SELECT u FROM Usermaster u WHERE u.username = :username"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Usermaster.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM Usermaster u WHERE u.password = :password"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Usermaster.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM Usermaster u WHERE u.email = :email"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Usermaster.findByProfilePic", query = "SELECT u FROM Usermaster u WHERE u.profilePic = :profilePic"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Usermaster.findByName", query = "SELECT u FROM Usermaster u WHERE u.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Usermaster.findByContactNo", query = "SELECT u FROM Usermaster u WHERE u.contactNo = :contactNo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Usermaster.findByStatus", query = "SELECT u FROM Usermaster u WHERE u.status = :status")})
public class Usermaster implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 32)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
    @Column(name = "mapLocation")
    private String mapLocation;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 32)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "profilePic")
    private String profilePic;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "contactNo")
    private String contactNo;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "status")
    private boolean status;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "usermaster")
    private College college;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "usermaster")
    private Student student;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "usermaster")
    private University university;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "username")
    private List<Detailnotification> detailnotificationList;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "usermaster")
    private Faculty faculty;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "usermaster")
    private List<Groupmaster> groupmasterList;

    public Usermaster() {
    }

    public Usermaster(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Usermaster(String username, String password, String address, String mapLocation, String email, String profilePic, String name, String contactNo, boolean status) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.address = address;
        this.mapLocation = mapLocation;
        this.email = email;
        this.profilePic = profilePic;
        this.name = name;
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getMapLocation() {
        return mapLocation;
    }

    public void setMapLocation(String mapLocation) {
        this.mapLocation = mapLocation;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getProfilePic() {
        return profilePic;
    }

    public void setProfilePic(String profilePic) {
        this.profilePic = profilePic;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }

    public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }

    public boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public College getCollege() {
        return college;
    }

    public void setCollege(College college) {
        this.college = college;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public University getUniversity() {
        return university;
    }

    public void setUniversity(University university) {
        this.university = university;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Detailnotification> getDetailnotificationList() {
        return detailnotificationList;
    }

    public void setDetailnotificationList(List<Detailnotification> detailnotificationList) {
        this.detailnotificationList = detailnotificationList;
    }

    public Faculty getFaculty() {
        return faculty;
    }

    public void setFaculty(Faculty faculty) {
        this.faculty = faculty;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Groupmaster> getGroupmasterList() {
        return groupmasterList;
    }

    public void setGroupmasterList(List<Groupmaster> groupmasterList) {
        this.groupmasterList = groupmasterList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (username != null ? username.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Usermaster)) {
            return false;
        }
        Usermaster other = (Usermaster) object;
        if ((this.username == null && other.username != null) || (this.username != null && !this.username.equals(other.username))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.Usermaster[ username=" + username + " ]";
    }

}
```

The medthod in Statless Bean

```
@Override
public List<University> getAllUniversitys() {
    try {
        return em.createNamedQuery("University.findAll").getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error :- " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

The Managed Bean code where it is called through Web Service

```
public List<University> getAllUniversity() {

    try {
        adminService.AdminBl adminPort = service.getAdminBlPort();
        return adminPort.getAllUniversitys();
        //return oAdminBlLocal.getAllUniversitys();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error :- " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;

}
```

And this is the error:

```
Severe:   Error occured
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: entity.University[ universityUname=abc ] -> entity.Usermaster[ username=abc ] -> entity.University[ universityUname=abc ]]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:424)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:192)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.saaj.SAAJFactory.readAsSOAPMessage(SAAJFactory.java:285)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.saaj.SAAJFactory.read(SAAJFactory.java:163)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.readAsSOAPMessage(AbstractMessageImpl.java:249)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.SOAPMessageContextImpl.getMessage(SOAPMessageContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.MessageTraceImpl.setMessageContext(MessageTraceImpl.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.JAXWSEndpointImpl.processResponse(JAXWSEndpointImpl.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:150)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:209)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:419)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:868)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.handlePost(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.invoke(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.dispatchToEjbEndpoint(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:210)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:153)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.doServletService(ServletHandler.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.service(ServletHandler.java:174)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: entity.University[ universityUname=abc ] -> entity.Usermaster[ username=abc ] -> entity.University[ universityUname=abc ]]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.BridgeImpl.marshal(BridgeImpl.java:94)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.api.Bridge.marshal(Bridge.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.BridgeWrapper.marshal(BridgeWrapper.java:192)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:417)
    ... 51 more
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Entity associations attempt to generate deeply nested XML elements and need to be excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is really self-explanatory:
 *A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: entity.University[ universityUname=abc ] -> entity.Usermaster[ username=abc ] -> entity.University[ universityUname=abc ]]*

Just add `@XmlTransient` to `Usermaster.getUniversity()` to break the cycle.

Comment: i changed it as you suggested but the error is still not solved.

Comment: Make sure you have recompiled, and check that the exception message is **exactly** the same. Probably there are other cycles with other entities: just individuate them and add @XmlTransient

Comment: yes there were other entites too .
@Michele thank you for helping